# What's the font used on HBO's on air promotion?

Tags: font-identification

It's a sans serif like Futura or Neutraface or Gotham or Brandon--but, it's got sharp corners (unlike Brandon), and the central point of the cap M reaches the baseline. And, it's a point--it's not cut off flat.

Comment: Posting a sample would be a good idea.

Comment: Also please try http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ first

Comment: I don't have a sample. It's only on TV, not on the website.

Comment: Take a picture the next time you see it on TV! It's very difficult to identify a font without a sample.

Comment: A sans like Futura with an M which touches the baseline in a point is **Kabel** but there's not really any way to be sure without seeing it, and some of us (in the UK) don't get HBO.

Comment: It's quite difficult to see what's being asked without a sample, so it's been put On Hold for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their website uses Gotham, and their on-air promotions use either Helvetica or Kabel (depending on which promotion you're seeing), in all capital letters.

Comment: This was found by doing some research and comparing results with screenshots of the promotion. I didn't personally figure it out.

Comment: So could you have added a screenshot of the promotion to the question, and definitively identified the font?